# Unable to execute dynamic sql Error:global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a remote table with blob column accessed via a db link. I want to insert a blob from my local table to remote table blob column.I am executing dynamic `sql` like follows

```
declare
    theblob blob;
    theclob clob;
    thenumber number;
begin
   select base64encode2(image) into theclob from per_images where image_id = 113077;
   execute immediate 'insert into image@APPSERP2ERPAPPS(column1,column2,column3) values((select null from dual),(select base64encode2(image) from per_images where image_id = 113077),(select ceil(5.4) from dual))';
   commit; 
end;
```

When i run the `sql` i get **ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation**.

If i do `ALTER SESSION SET GLOBAL_NAMES = true` then i get **database link APPSERP2ERPAPPS.CSN.EDU.PK connects to TEST.CSN.EDU.PK** error while inserting into blob.

Kindly tell me how can i insert blob into remote table blob column.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you looked for connectivity issues or something related, had you tried without 'values' like here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9529803800346305193

Comment: when i insert null it gives no error. INSERT INTO image@APPSERP2ERPAPPS SELECT * FROM mview but same error

Comment: @karelss Thanks man. the link you gave works.

Comment: You are wellcome i'm going to put this as answer, can you post here the final solution

Comment: yes please sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to insert over a dblink the insert sentence must match this format

```
Insert into table2@dblink select * from Table1
```

[here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9529803800346305193) more info.